# Concatenate text, substitute reference, and evaluate as formula

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am stringing together a formula using CONCATENATE which results in a text that looks like:

```
=-10*IF((x-10)^3<0,0,(x-10)^3)-20*IF((x-2)^3<0,0,(x-2)^3)
```

Now, I need to replace "x" with a cell reference (A1, A2, A3, etc.). After that, I want the text to be evaluated as a formula.

I have tried using something to the effect of:

```
=Eval(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(B1,C1,D1),"x",A1))
```

Where Eval is a macro:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
Application.Volatile
Eval = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

However, I get a #VALUE error. I've tried doing this a lot of different ways and this is the closest I got.

Am I going about this completely wrong or am I on the right track?

Comment: Try placing `A1` in quotes `"A1"` in your Substitute formula.

Comment: What are the exact text in B1,C1 and D1?  In B1 how are you dealing with the fact that Excel will see it as a formula and return an error?

Comment: because I put your formula in D1 and 100 in A1 and using your formula and function I get an answer of `-26113840`

Comment: That's the thing - the exact text in B1, C1, and D1 isn't direct text - it is a string that was constructed based on IF statements. I think the Eval function is having trouble because it isn't direct text that I put into a cell, then concatenating and substituting before evaluating. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't want to place "A1" in the Substitute formula because I want to drag drown this equation that I constructed to evaluate A1:A500 for instance. - Thanks for the help, by the way.